# extjs TreePanel dont work with metro webview app

Tags: extjs, webview, microsoft-metro, treepanel

I'm using sencha/extjs 3.4 TreePanel in my web application and when i'v made metro app with webview navigating to my application the problem is that when i click a node on treePanel nothing happens. Is that a common problem or i did smth wrong. Everything works in IE10, just not in the metro webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was that mine application dont work at ie10 with ie10 standards and i'm using emulateIE7, which for some reason dont work at metro webview